# Get all groups for a specific web site (NOT SITE COLLECTION) using powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, spweb, spuser, spgroup

I would like to know how to get all groups of a specific web site using powershell.
I do know that all groups are defined at the site collection level but when browsing in a specific web, it only displays groups that are associated with the current web.

So there must be a way to know what is the web associated for a specific group or what are all groups associated with a specific web.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties.aspx) helped me out.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl;
$groups = $web.AssociatedGroups;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 the Web Object has different properties to get site groups and web groups.

`$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
//Gets a collection that contains all the groups in the site collection.
$siteGroups = $web.SiteGroups
//Gets a collection that contains all the groups for the website. This return SPGroupCollection object and listed groups will be assigned security roles assigned in a current site
$webGroups = $web.Groups
//Gets a collection that contains all the groups for the website. This returns all web groups but some group may not have securoty roles assigned.
$webGroups = $web.AssociatedGroups`

You can refer the web properties and methods here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties(v=office.14).aspx